# How to create a custom API in magento 2 which can be accessed by all the customers only?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, customer, api

I need to create a custom API which can be accessed by all the customers only in magento 2 . Please help.

Comment: all customer means? login or guest or both?

Comment: @MeetaliGupta have you resolved your query?

Comment: @MuhammadHasham, yes its resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml`

Add `registration.php` in your module

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

There are two more additional configurations we need to add API capability to module, webapi.xml and di.xml. In webapi.xml we are configuring access rights and API Interface that specified method will use.

Web API configuration – `etc/webapi.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/hello/name/:name" method="GET">
        <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\HelloInterface" method="name"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Resource tag defines what resources user needs to have to be able to access this api call. Possible options are self, anonymous or Magento resource like Magento_Catalog::products or Magento_Customer::group. We will for now use anonymous so we can access it as a guest.

Define Interface – `etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\HelloInterface"
                type="Vendor\Module\Model\Hello" />
</config>
```

In di.xml we define what model will interface call to. We also need to add Interface and Model, please note that you need to take care about comments also.

Interface – `Api/HelloInterface.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Api;

interface HelloInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $name Users name.
     * @return string Greeting message with users name.
     */
    public function name($name);
}
```

Model – `Model/Hello.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
use Vendor\Module\Api\HelloInterface;

class Hello implements HelloInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $name Users name.
     * @return string Greeting message with users name.
     */
    public function name($name) {
        return "Hello, " . $name;
    }
}
```

> Communicating with new API call

**Testing as guest**

To test REST you can go to http://{domain_name}/rest/V1/{method}/{attribute}/{value}.

Example: http://magento2.loc/rest/V1/hello/name/Jim.

This is how response should look like for this example:

```
<response>Hello, Jim</response>
```

Adding ACL

If we don’t set anonymous in resource of webapi.xml, we need to set existing Magento resource or create our own. We can do that by adding acl.xml to etc.

ACL – `etc/acl.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Vendor_Module::hello" title="Hello" translate="title" sortOrder="110" />
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Reference: https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-custom-api/

**I hope this will help**